# Creating a role for an on-premise server to assume for AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-code-deploy

I'm following the tutorial found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/register-on-premises-instance-iam-session-arn.html) to use an on-premise server with CodeDeploy. I'm a little confused with the first couple of steps. When I'm creating a role for the on-premise server to assume, what should I choose as the service that will use this role (in the console)? I do understand what policy the role should have, allowing actions `s3:Get` and `s3:List` for all resources. To provide additional info, I want to use the `aws-codedeploy-session-helper` tool to periodically refresh the session credentials for me, and the policy for the IAM user this tool uses is as follows:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow", 
      "Action": [
        "iam:CreateAccessKey",
        "iam:CreateUser",
        "iam:DeleteAccessKey",
        "iam:DeleteUser",
        "iam:DeleteUserPolicy",
        "iam:ListAccessKeys",
        "iam:ListUserPolicies",
        "iam:PutUserPolicy",
        "iam:GetUser",
        "iam:AddRoleToInstanceProfile",
        "iam:CreateInstanceProfile",
        "iam:CreateRole",
        "iam:DeleteInstanceProfile",
        "iam:DeleteRole",
        "iam:DeleteRolePolicy",
        "iam:GetInstanceProfile",
        "iam:GetRole",
        "iam:GetRolePolicy",
        "iam:ListInstanceProfilesForRole",
        "iam:ListRolePolicies",
        "iam:ListRoles",
        "iam:PassRole",
        "iam:PutRolePolicy",
        "iam:RemoveRoleFromInstanceProfile",
        "autoscaling:*",
        "codedeploy:*",
        "ec2:*",
        "lambda:*",
        "elasticloadbalancing:*", 
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to allow the on-premise server to call the STS assume role API, so the service should "STS"

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT-ID>:role/<ROLENAME>"
  }
}
```

Then in the IAM Role, add a "Trust" Policy for the server.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT-ID>:user/<USER-NAME>"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Ah, the "Principal" part of the trust policy is what I was messing up.  Thank you for your help.